# Definine a synthetic service in Symfony 4.1 doesn't work from within a bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am creating a Symfony Bundle that defines a synthetic service:

```
my_alias:
    public: true
    synthetic: true
```

After installing the bundle, the application's console command `cache:clear` always fails with the error:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException]
>     Invalid service "my_alias": class "" does not exist.

If I create the same alias inside the actual framework, this error does not turn up.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In which file are you injecting `my_alias` in the container? We may need to see more code about this to understand ?

Answer (score 0):

When you clear the cache the kernel is recompiled and the container will not figure out your service that is not injected to the container, that's why you need to inject it under your Kernel class:

```
if (!$container->hasDefinition('my_alias')) {
    $container->set('my_alias', new SyntheticService());
}
```

Comment: In the Kernel in `configureContainer`, `$container->hasDefinition('my_alias')` returns false, so this doesn't work. Additionally, why would the fact that the bundle defines the service be different from my application defining the service? I don't see the difference.

Comment: In fact it's a typo should be has not a definition with `!`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. The question was how to do this from within a bundle. I'm currently having the same issue, but I don't want to tell all users of my bundle that they have to modify their kernel to get it working. 
Is this really the way that symfony intended synthetic services to be used? That every user of a bundle with a synthetic service has to make changes to their kernel?